# Complex number modulus inequality

Tags: complex-numbers

I was going over the complex numbers and I came across the following inequality in my notes: $|z_1 + z_2| \leq z_1 + z_2$.

Is this correct? Because it doesn't look that way to me. And if so, what is the correct version, and in what kinds of exercises would this property be useful?

Comment: Inequalities between complex numbers are meaningless. You need to have inequalities between moduli of complex numbers. If you put modulus signs round the z's on the right, it would be a true statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have meant $|z_1+z_2| \leq |z_1| + |z_2|$. You can only have comparisons ($\leq$, $\geq$ etc.) between *real* numbers.